# Is there a standard reader applicative instance?

Tags: haskell

Is there an already existing instance like one I found in this [blog post](http://comonad.com/reader/2012/abstracting-with-applicatives/)?

```
data Reader r a = Reader (r -> a)
instance Functor (Reader r) where
    fmap f (Reader x) = Reader (f . x)
instance Applicative (Reader r) where
    pure x = Reader $ pure x
    (Reader f) <*> (Reader x) = Reader (f <*> x)
```

Comment: All monads are applicatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. By the time `Applicative` itself is in scope, an instance for `(->) r` is in scope as well. (And that has to be true for the code you wrote to even type-check -- did you notice that the `Applicative` instance for `Reader` is just shipping out to the `Applicative` instance for `(->) r`? =)